# How to implement Semantic Search in R or Python

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, information-retrieval, similar-documents

I have a task to provide semantic searching capabilities. For example, if I have a dataset of resume and if I search for "machine learning" than it should return me all resumes which have data science-related skills despite of missing "machine learning" keyword. How do we search the data through its meaning and related keywords I wonder? I have checked many algorithms also Like LSA, LDA, LSI but cannot find a resource which gives the implementation of the above.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible options.

One option is to create a dictionary of related terms. Then look for documents that contain those related terms.

This can be done with built-in data structures like Python's `dict` and pattern matching tools like regular expression (regex).

Answer (score 0):

I can see two ways to do this:

1. Rule based approach:

You can create a list of keywords such as following:

`keywords = ['machine-learning', 'machine learning', 'AI', ...]`

And then you can search through the documents that you have.

2. BERT based approach:

Here is some base code that you might use:

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel
import torch

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
```

```py
def encode(text):
    inputs = tokenizer.encode_plus(text, return_tensors='pt', max_length=512, truncation=True)
    outputs = model(**inputs)
    return outputs.last_hidden_state[:, 0, :].detach().numpy()

resumes = [...]  # list of resumes
resume_vectors = [encode(resume) for resume in resumes]
query_vector = encode("machine learning")
```

```py
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

similarities = [cosine_similarity(query_vector, resume_vector) for resume_vector in resume_vectors]
```

```py
top_resumes = sorted(zip(resumes, similarities), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

You can use this approach to find similar words from the resumes using `cosine similarity`.